# Change color of javascript brackets and operators in Visual Studio 11

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Anyone know how to change the bracket and operator colors for VS11 Developer Preview? It must be a new entry under Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors but I'm having trouble finding it. Below is a screenshot from a script block in a .htm file to illustrate symbols affected:
[image]

Note that the color is not applied to .cs files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the JS operators, change the **Script Operator** display item. 
Items affected: `: + - / * = ,`

The **Plain Text** display item changes the brackets (among others). 
Items affected: `; { } ( ) [ ]`